# Vi stuck in undo/redo toggle with u commands?

Tags: vim, vi

I have no idea why this is happening, but on all my rackspace servers vi is doing unwanted behavior when I try using u.

Example -- starting line:

```
//Here is a comment
```

Using xx (delete) to delete the slashes and get:

```
Here is a comment
```

Now when I try using u, I expect pressing it twice will return me to my previous commented line but instead I get (first u):

```
/Here is a comment
```

and then pressing a second u:

```
Here is a comment
```

It will only ever toggle the last edit over and over. I don't know if this is a setting in Ubuntu 13.10, rackspace or what but on every other server I just use u with no problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to turn off `vi` compatibility. Create a `~/.vimrc` file and put this in it:

```
set nocompatible
```

Comment: +1, here is the relevant bit of documentation: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#undo-two-ways

Comment: Just having `.vimrc`, even an empty one, should set `nocompatible`.

Comment: In case something ever breaks the sourceforge link, the internet archive has it available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20230201000524/https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#undo-two-ways